# Javascript: What is the event will trigger before click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have around 20 to 25 Java script methods already available in my js file. Now, I want to perform some validation methods needs to be triggered before the click event of some method.
How to achieve this without modifying existing 25 methods?

```
<div id="div1" onclick="onDiv1Click('Exc')">Test</div>
<div id="div2" onclick="onDiv2Click(pram1,param2)">Test 2 div</div>
<div id="div3" onclick="onDiv3Click()">Test 3 div</div>
<div id="div4" onclick="onDiv4Click(param1)">Test 4 div</div>

function onDiv1Click(obj){
// perform some operation
}
function onDiv2Click(obj,obj){
// perform some operation
}

function onDiv3Click(){
// perform some operation
}
function onDiv4Click(obj){
// perform some operation
}



function newValidationmethod(){
 //my validation logic goes here
}
```

Now, I want to call newValidationmethod() before onDiv1click() event. if validation method return ture, then i need to execute onDiv1click method.

Comment: You can use `keyup` or `keydown` event for validation.

Comment: what you have done so far ?

Comment: mouseenter(), mousedown() are the events which you want have on your elements before click() gets triggers.

Comment: let me explain you in detail

Comment: some validation methods needs to be triggered before? on what you need to trigger,the textbox or controls or something else.What does those 25 methods written for?To handle click events or some validation or calculation or?Do write in brief.Always you need to have some event or at least timer to perform js actions.

Comment: Updated the question with an example

Answer (score 1):

Add an event listener to the document, and make sure it runs on the **capture phase**:

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(event){
    //Whatever
},true);
```

Example modified from [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_addeventlistener.asp). Note `jquery` always bubbles, so you have to use the vanilla `addEventListener` with last argument `true`.

To stop the event from propagating in the function (failed validation) you can use:

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

Comment: will it effect the other click event bind to that specific button ?

Comment: should we add this event to specific element or document?

Comment: @MuhammadUzair If you want this to trigger on multiple different events bound to different elements, then you will have to bind it to the document to make it work after all your listeners (with the last argument true). If you are only working on a single element, bind to that, but that was a different question than this one.

Answer (score 0):

i guess these ideas that may help, check code case sensitivity if it is correct because i wrote without check:

```
   <a id="myid" onclick="if(notvalid()) return false; YourOldMethod();" />

    OR

    $(function(){
         $("#myid").onclick(function(){

             if(notvalid()) return false; 

             YourOldMethod();

         });

    });
```

Comment: Then I need to add "if(notvalid()) return false; " this line in all my 25 div's right? Without editing 25 elements, how to achieve this?

Comment: Example:

its like pseudo code not real working code:

$("div").each(function(){

if($(this).attr("onclick") != "") 
$(this).attr("onclick", "if(notvalid()) return false; " + $(this).attr("onclick"));
});

Comment: let me try this. Thanks